# AngularJS ng-controller

Tags: angularjs

Guys please check my below code, Why its not working..

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>          
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title> 
</head> 
<body ng-app>
        <h1 ng-controller="HWCtrl">{{helloMessage}}</h1>

        <srcipt src="angular.js"></srcipt>
        <script type="text/javascript">                 
                function HWCtrl($scope) {
                    $scope.helloMessage = 'Hello World';
                }

        </script>
</body>
```

I created HWCtrl function for a ng-controller.. Thanks in advance

Comment: what is not working please be specific ?

Comment: Is the path to your angular.js file correct. Your code works fine as seen here at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ewaY/1/edit)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about typo

Answer (score 4):

You misspelled `script`:

```
<srcipt src="angular.js"></srcipt>
  ^-- here                   ^-- and here
```